# Mocking IJSRuntime for Blazor Component unit tests

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, blazor

Following [this prototype](https://blog.stevensanderson.com/2019/08/29/blazor-unit-testing-prototype/) for unit testing I've ran into a problem when using JS interop.

```
[Test]
public void ExampleTest()
{
    var component = host.AddComponent<MyComponent>();
}
```

Just adding a component that uses IJSRuntime will cause the following exception

> System.InvalidOperationException : Cannot provide a value for property 'JsRuntime' on type 'Application.Components.MyComponent'. There is no registered service of type 'Microsoft.JSInterop.IJSRuntime'.

The JS interop isn't doing anything of interest, it's just a void function that focuses an element - I don't care about testing it, I just want to be able to proceed with writing tests for the component itself.

How can I use Moq to mock IJSRuntime?

When I try something like

```
[Test]
public void ExampleTest()
{
    var jsRuntimeMock = new Mock<IJSRuntime>();

    host.AddService(jsRuntimeMock);

    var component = host.AddComponent<MyComponent>();
}
```

I still get the exception

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
host.AddService(jsRuntimeMock);
```

registers `Mock<IJSRuntime>` as a dependency.

No classes in the implementation (outside of a test assembly) should have such a dependency but it's a common error to make.

Register `IJSRuntime` as a dependency using the `Mock<T>` property `Object`, which contains a reference to an object that implements the interface.

Like this:

```
host.AddService(jsRuntimeMock.Object);
```

Comment: Great, small misunderstanding on my part I guess. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft uses a lot of internal Singletons and therefore having test on application Level very very difficult and you should replace all Default Services like IJSRuntime, NavigationManager and NavigationInterceptor. I hope in the next preview there will be an easy way to create a unittest methods and simulate the browser.